# Prove that the cdf is strictly increasing on the support if the support is a finite interval

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, measure-theory

I am trying to prove that that for a distribution $P$ with cdf $F$, if the support of $P$ is a finite interval $I=[a,b]$ then $F$ will be strictly increasing on $I$.

It's probably a simple application of measure-theory, but I can't quite prove it.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This appears to be a self-study question, so please add the `self-study` tag and [read its wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), which includes guidance for asking such questions.  This includes showing that you have made a 'good faith' attempt at solving the problem yourself.  Please edit your question to include how far you have got in your proof and tell us where you are stuck, so that other users can nudge you in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F(x):=P(X\leq x)$. Since $F(x)$ is increasing on $[a,b]$, if it is not strictly increasing then there are two points $y,z\in [a,b]$ with $y<z$ such that $F(y)=F(z)$. By definition of probability measures:

$$0=F(z)-F(y)=P(y<X\leq z).$$

Since $y<z$ this necessarily implies $(y,z]\notin\mbox{supp}(X)=[a,b]$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I guess I was too stuck in a tunnelvision of having to use the derivative and making a constructive prove to see that the solution was this easy...